# How c compiler works the same everywhere

Tags: c

I have read that c was made to build the unix os.
But now the same c can be used to make programs in windows , linux and almost every operating systems
How is this possible.
Windows executable have a different structure with linux and vise versa
They may use different mnuemonics to define the program but how will this same c compiler compile programs for different systems

Comment: `Windows executable have a different structure` Yeah, and the compiler knows that. What's the problem?

Comment: It's not necessarily the same compiler for all OS. It's a compiler for Linux/Unix, a compiler for Windows, etc.

Comment: So my question is that , if different os have different compilers , why they call it c . you have stated that different os have different compiler so that they have to remake the whole compiler

Comment: "C" describes the language that is input into the compiler.   The output (compiled executable) differs from one OS to another, from platform to platform, but the input is consistent.

Comment: So , do you mean that only the mnuemonic constants change and not everything

Comment: What do you mean by mnemonic constants? And they don’t have to remake the whole compiler. The language doesn’t change, the hardware may be the same...

Comment: The C language is a formal specification (on paper). A C compiler is an implementation (i.e a program) of this specification specific for a OS.

Comment: Remember that GCC is the "GNU Compiler Collection" -- one codebase, but with lots of different language frontends and lots of different backends able to generate executables for different operating systems' ABIs. Building software with optional pieces that can be mixed-and-matched at runtime is a matter of *engineering*; a question of "but how do they do that?" is far too broad to be topical on SO -- there literally *are* books about the design of GCC (and other compilers).

Comment: From [What type of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), note the guidance that "if you can imagine a book that answers your question, you're asking too much". And if imagining a book is tricky, you can take inspiration from [the GCC project's list of compiler books](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ListOfCompilerBooks).

Comment: What is the purpose of down voting a question , I have asked it here because i can quickly get the answer. If there's an easy way , why should i use a hard way to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same compiler. You use a Linux C compiler to compile programs for Linux (such as gcc or clang). You use a Windows C compiler to compile programs for Windows (such as Microsoft Visual Studio, but also the Windows versions of gcc or clang).

There are a lot of standard C functions that you can call that work on Windows and Linux (for example `fopen` or `printf`), but if you call any Windows-specific or Linux-specific functions (such as `CreateWindow` or `gettimeofday`) then your program won't compile on other operating systems.

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to know about how the standard libraries differ (so long as that library is described with a header that's compilable with the standard C language), so that's neither here nor there. Differing ABIs and executable formats are a slightly bigger deal, but even then, it's isolated subsystems involved.

Comment: (...an illustrative example: If I `#include` a header that defines an implementation of `gettimeofday()` on Windows, am I suddenly running a different compiler? Of course not! Thus, whether headers defining functions you need and libraries implementing them are locally available is an unrelated concern).